# How to clone an object in TypeScript?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, asynchronous

I'm trying to pass a modified clone of an object `credential.user` to a function

```
const credential = await this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password);
var userInfo=  await credential.user

userInfo.displayName=  name

return this.updateUserData(userInfo);
```

however I am getting this message:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: "displayName" is read-only
emailLogin/<@http://localhost:4200
```

How can I clone this object received from an async function and modify one of its attributes?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use the spread operator to copy all properties but then overwrite the `displayName` with your desired value:

```js
const credential = await this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password);
var userInfo = await credential.user;

return this.updateUserData({
  ...userInfo,
  displayName: name
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to do deal with a similar issue the other day and even creating a new object and using the spread operator to copy didn't get around this issue.

What *did* work was:

```
const userCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(userInfo))
```

This creates a copy that is completely disassociated from the original.